# Return cell value by criteria in same row AND row above

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

This is a very complicated question. 
I'm not even sure if what I'm hoping for is possible, but I have been surprised many times before. Here we go....

Here are the links to the two spreadsheets I am modeling my situation after:
[John Doe](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14p99iCk8HW6K4ksuvMw8fuVF8ZzTuc-UZ0uCUY3dYtU/edit#gid=435089700) and
[Jane Doe](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rrshg9qcShUCqQDEhp74aRHzcyDRgsh5IWM60Lypup8/edit#gid=435089700).

In these spreadsheets, I recently set up a script for making dynamic dropdown lists according to this video: [DYNAMIC DEPENDENT DROP DOWN LISTS IN GOOGLE SPREADSHEETS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rW9T4XZy-7U&t=434s). It works great for me, but there is a whole level on top of it that I need to establish. First and foremost, be aware that I cannot move any of the cells/rows/columns.

In my system here, I have two individuals working on a TASK (TASK1), one a Writer and the other a Reviewer. The John Doe, for example, will log their task (TASK1), and in the Total line they will indicate the TASK TYPE (Write) and WRITING PARTNER (Jane Doe). Jane Doe will do the same and then give John Doe a score after her review in column O. The roles here could also be switched-- for example, see TASK2, where Jane Doe is the Writer this time and John Doe is the Reviewer.

The difference is the formula in column F under SCORE, where it populates differently according to the TASK TYPE specified in the individual's sheet: If it is specified as a Review task for that person, it will populate with the score their Reviewer gave; if it is not specified as a Review task, it will be kept blank; if their Reviewer has not yet left a Score, it will populate the placeholder "(Score)"; and lastly, if it is specified as a Write task.......

....the idea is that I want it to populate with the SCORE value in column F for the task having the same TASK NAME in whoever's spreadsheet is specified in the WRITING PARTNER column. I've figured out how to dynamically import the correct spreadsheet using a VLOOKUP within an IMPORTRANGE function: `IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP(E4,'Named Ranges'!B:D,3,FALSE),"'2019'!whateverrangeIneed")`

But beyond that, I haven't figured out how to return the correct value from Jane Doe's spreadsheet into John Doe's spreadsheet. Please see my attempts in John Doe's spreadsheet. The biggest issue is that I need to use not only column A="Total" as a criteria, but also column B ***of the row above the total***="The TASK NAME to reference". If I could figure that out, I could paste that formula into "FORMULATOSOLVE" of the function in column F.
Ultimately, the point is to be able to report an Average Score for John Doe the Writer, based on his review scores, using the formula `AVERAGE(FILTER('2019'!F:F,'2019'!D:D="Write",'2019'!E:E<>"None"))`.

As mentioned, I've recently used a script for the first time, so I'm not opposed to doing that here as well if needed, but I don't have the know-how to write it myself.

Thank you immensely for any help.

Comment: can you provide example of desired output?

Comment: The formula should output the selected reviewer's (Jane Doe's) score for the task with the same name (TASK1), which in this case should be 5.

Comment: Have you tried to do it with apps script? With a switch condition it would be much easier to put the specific result and you can select any spreadsheet by ID.

Comment: And could you please make the question easier to understand, I don't know which values you need from Jane sheet or how the 5 is calculated, if Jane's sheet always has 2 tasks before the total, etc. Thank you

Comment: @Kessy I'm not well-versed enough in Javascript to be able to write my own apps script alone, but I'm open to it. To clarify my question, I need the score in column F of the Total line from Jane Doe's sheet. Jane Doe's sheet will not necessarily only have 2 task lines above the total. It could have one or many. I included the TASK2 in her log to demonstrate that different tasks will have different scores, and that I need to import the specific score for a task by using the task name in column B as a criteria. Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: Is the writers sheets dynamic as well, could it have more than one task? would it be possible to create, at least on the writers, a static template?

Comment: @Kessy I think I'm understanding your question... It is possible that for another task, John Doe could be the Reviewer and Jane Doe could be the Writer, which is why I need them both to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tried Apps Script I have written this simple script that does what you need.
This will work with the amount of Tasks that you want, since iterates over all the column length.

```
function getScore() {

  // GET the two sheets
  var writer = SpreadsheetApp.openById('WRITER SHEET ID').getSheetByName('2019');
  var reviewer =  SpreadsheetApp.openById('REVIEWER SHEET ID').getSheetByName('2019');

  // Get the B column of each sheet
  var writerTask = writer.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
  var reviewerTask = reviewer.getRange("B2:B").getValues();

  // Variables to save data
  var writerScore = '';
  var taskName = '';

  // Iterate over every single row in column B of writer
  for (var i = 1; i < writerTask.length; i++) {

    // Check if the actual row is empty (which means is the total row)
    // and also check if the row before is not empty
    if (writerTask[i] == '' && writerTask[i-1] != ''){

      // Assign the values inside the previous row to taskName (will be TASK1)
      taskName =  writerTask[i-1].toString();

      // Get the cell where the score has to go
      writerScore = writer.getRange('F'+(i+2))

      // Iterate over the reviewers sheet
      for (var j = 1; j < reviewerTask.length; j++) {

        // Check if cell is empty and check the previous cell has the same
        // value from the one on the writers sheet
        if (reviewerTask[j-1].toString() == taskName && reviewerTask[j] == ''){ 

          // Assign the value from the cell on reviewers sheet to the cell on the writers sheet
          writerScore.setValue(reviewer.getRange('F'+(j+2)).getValue());
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

To run the script you can set up a button on the sheet you want, see: [Clickable images and drawings in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets)

Comment: thank you for the script! My concern is how the script gets the right Sheet ID. I think this would work if there was only one possible Reviewer/Writer, but the roles are interchangeable and there is more than one possibility for who either could be. I don't know scripts well, but I think the steps that need to happen are 1) go to current total line 2) determine if column D=Write, and if so 3) get correct task name in column B 4) get sheet of the person named in column E 5) find the same task name in said person's sheet 5) go to total line of said task 6) get score value in column F.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood it right, try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(D4="Write", VLOOKUP(E4&B3, 
 {IMPORTRANGE("1rrshg9qcShUCqQDEhp74aRHzcyDRgsh5IWM60Lypup8", "2019!E2:E1000")&
  IMPORTRANGE("1rrshg9qcShUCqQDEhp74aRHzcyDRgsh5IWM60Lypup8", "2019!B1:B1000"), 
  IMPORTRANGE("1rrshg9qcShUCqQDEhp74aRHzcyDRgsh5IWM60Lypup8", "2019!F2:F1001")}, 2, 0),
 IF(D4="Review", IF(O4="", "(Score)", O4), )), "no data"))
```

[image]

---

note to allow access beforehand you do above:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm mostly understanding the function. But when I try it in John Doe's work log it gives me "no data". And I think I would need to change the Importrange to the Vlookup I gave above, so that the range changes with the name in column E: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(D4="Write", VLOOKUP(E4&B3, 
 {IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP(E4,'Named Ranges'!B:D,3,FALSE),"2019!B1:B1000")&
  IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP(E4,'Named Ranges'!B:D,3,FALSE),"2019!B1:B1000"), 
  IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP(E4,'Named Ranges'!B:D,3,FALSE),"2019!B1:B1000")}, 2, 0),
 IF(D4="Review", IF(O4="", "(Score)", O4), )), "no data"))`

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved. The script and formula in use can be seen in the google sheets by following the links. The script used was:

```
function WriterScore(projectName, importedSheet){

  // Create a set of variables
  var foundScore = false;
  var score = "";
  var data = importedSheet;

  while(foundScore == false){
    for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
      if(data[i][1] == projectName){
        for(var q = i; q<data.length;q++){
          if(data[q][1] == projectName){
          }else{
            score = data[q][5]
            return score
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if(score == ""){
      return "You do not have a project by that name.";
    }
  }

  return score
}
```

And the final cell formula was:

`=IF(D7="Write",WriterScore(B6,IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP(E7,'Named Ranges'!B:D,3,FALSE),"'2019'!A:F")),IF(D7="Review",IF(O7="","(Score)",O7),""))`